# SQL SELECT If (a="") Then change b value

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

This seems like a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer. I am basically trying to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
IF(columnA > 0) BEGIN
columnB = 'Greater than 0'
END
```

I don't want the value to change in the table, I just want it to change in the result. ANy suggestions?

Comment: use a [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) expression

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SELECT  ColumnA
        , case when ColumnA > 0 then 'Greater than 0' else ColumnB END AS ColumnB 
FROM    table1;
```

Comment: Wont this just change columnA from 0 to 'Greater than 0' rather than columnB?

Comment: Tyler, it's only *checking* columnA as the condition for the case statement.  The second column is either "Greater than 0" or the table value of ColumnB.  Try it.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
SELECT columnA, IIF(columnA > 0, 'Greater than 0', columnB)
  FROM table1;
```

Comment: I don't think "IF" is a function that takes 3 parameters.

Comment: I was just informed that there's an "IIF" function.  I'll assume that's what you meant, then slap myself in the head.  Please edit so I may upvote!

Comment: @NickVaccaro - See the docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: @TedHopp this is a `sql-server`-tagged question

Comment: @TedHopp np. I like `IIF` better in this 'case' (pun intended)